# Actual commands executed by Maven in a phase or goal

Tags: maven

This is probably a question on Maven internals, and I haven't had much luck searching and finding the answer. Concisely, I'm interested in seeing what commands Maven actually execute for each phase or goal. For example, `mvn package` creates the jar file, so I'd think it must call the `jar -cf` command at some point.

Maven is opinionated so by design, this command doesn't show up in the `.pom` file. But which commands does Maven actually run for a specific phase and goal? Is there a way to see them?

Answer (score 0):

The call creating a jar file is done in the [maven-jar-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/) which is bound to the life cycle. You can do a `mvn -X clean package` to what happens behind the scenes. But you won't see many commands (except for javac compiling)... What do you mean by: `Maven is opinionated so by design, this command doesn't show up in the .pom file`? 
The [life cycles](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.0/maven-core/lifecycles.html) shows what kind of phases run [bindings](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.0/maven-core/default-bindings.html) shows which plugins runs in which phase.

If you want to take a look into the sources of plugins all plugins can be found here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/
On the right side you can see links to the appropriate version control system with links to it.

Each plugin has a link to the source code for example maven-jar-plugin: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/source-repository.html

Answer (score 0):

Run `mvn` with the `-X` parameter, then look for lines starting with "[DEBUG] Executing command line:".

Answer (score -1):

All the plugins are written in Java (or JVM-based languages), so if you can read it - you can find out what it does. Here are for example sources of the maven-jar-plugin: [link1](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-jar-plugin-3.0.2/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/jar/JarMojo.java?view=markup), [link2](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-jar-plugin-3.0.2/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/jar/AbstractJarMojo.java?view=markup).

But to get there you need to figure out which plugins and goals are executed when you run a phase. There are multiple ways:

1. In the output Maven says which goals it executes, example:

> maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ module-name

2. If you generate an Effective POM, you'll be able to see all the plugins and which phases they are bound to: `mvn help:effective-pom`. Some plugins have default phases so people don't have to specify them explicitly - for these you'd have to look into the plugin meta information or into the sources.
3. Default plugins and goals are defined by the packaging. For the default packagings you could look into [default-bindings.xml](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=maven.git;a=blob;f=maven-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/default-bindings.xml) (role-hint is the packaging name).

After you know which plugins and goals are executed you can check out the sources of each plugin (the sources are usually open) and see its Mojos for the actual source code.

If you decide to learn the code it would be useful to be able to debug it when you run a `mvn` command. For that you can use `mvnDebug` instead of `mvn`.

More info: [click1](https://github.com/qala-io/java-course/blob/master/docs/programme/articles/maven-plugins.md), [click2](https://github.com/qala-io/java-course/blob/master/docs/programme/articles/maven-lifecycles-n-phases.md).

Comment: Life Cycles: https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.0/maven-core/lifecycles.html and bindings https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.0/maven-core/default-bindings.html.